# Raspberry pi stopped working

Tags: raspbian, sd-card, osmc, troubleshooting

I have a raspberry pi 2, and 2 micro SD cards, one with OSMC and the other with raspbian, but ever since a few days, OSMC wont boot, and if it boots, it freezes just a minute after booting, with the `ACT` and `PWR` led's on at the same time.

Now I tried booting with raspbian, and it boots, however when it is about to start `X11`, it freezes, with both led's on too.

Those are two different SD cards, with no common relation, except they both are plugged into the pi, and the power supply is just fine, with enough power, and the rainbow square is not showing up at all.

The 2 SD cards were just fine a week ago, and then suddenly they stopped working.
When I try to install a new OSMC in another SD card, it freezes at 20% estimated, and I don't know what its going on with it.

Comment: Writing on an SD card causes wear. If you use large capacity SD cards, the writes will be spread, and so will the wear. This may help to delay ageing issues. Using good quality cards will help to prevent problems too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You say "When i try to install a new osmc in another sd card, it freezes at 20% estimated". What freezes?  If the install is freezing, then it seems your sd card is suspect. If the install runs fine and pi freezes on boot, then we're troubleshooting a problem with the pi.

While it would seem unlikely two sd cards would go bad simultaneously, this is not impossible. It's possible the osmc sd card is horked. The raspbian one is in an unknown state so that one not booting doesn't really tell us anything.

If there's nothing important on the raspbian sd card, I would suggest reinstalling raspbian and see where that gets you. If you do have important data, try a 3rd sd card, preferably a known good one, or perhaps order a new one, a smaller 8g card is pretty cheap ($3-6) to help rule out problems with the two you have.

Personally, I have always purchased two boards: two pis, two Pi2s, two Beagles, etc. They are relatively cheap, so that's a great way to test for problems related to the board itself. Although for what it's worth, I've never had a pi die on me, it's always been something else.

Most recently, a power supply that had been working fine a year just stopped working one morning, with the symptoms being similar to what you describe: it would boot partway and then freeze. A 2nd supply I tried also didn't work, but having tried two power supplies I thought I'd ruled out that possibility and spent hours chasing other dead ends. It wasn't until I pulled a working supply from another running pi that I discovered power was the problem.